# How to add a ScrollBar at the bottom of the JPanel when using GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, jscrollbar

Hello i wanted to know how to add a ScrollBar at the bottom of a JPanel if i use GridLayout in my desktop app, as far as i know GridLayout only accept as parameter quantity of colums, rows and the horizontal and vertical gap. So how can i add a scroll bar and use it to see the information that's in the JPanel?

Comment: Use a different layout manager or a compound layout, something like `BorderLayout` or `GridBagLayout` should do the trick

Comment: if i use GridBag Layout how would i do that?

Comment: Use `JScrollPane` then

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `JPanel` with `GridLayout` into a `JScrollPane`.  E.G. as seen with the two column `GridLayout` that displays the labels added to the [nested layout example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/how-to-add-jtable-in-jpanel/5630271#5630271).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the JSrollBar to scroll the JPanel with the gridlayout, then put the grid layout into a scrollpane (remember to extend the scrollable interface)

Read [this page of the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components) to learn how to.

IF you want to use the events from the JScrollBar to change the visible area of your panel then put the panel inside another panel with a JScrollbar on the bottom.

This is an example with a green panel and a scrollbar at the bottom

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    public Window() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
        scrollBar.setMinimum(0);
        scrollBar.setMaximum(100);
        scrollBar.setBlockIncrement(30);
        scrollBar.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                 System.out.println("Adjustment changed");
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(scrollBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you go for the JScrollPane solution, remembar that you can hide the vertical scrollbar using the scroll policies. Read the documentation for that.

Comment: Could you please give an example of both situations?